# Will the promotional credits for GKE still apply individually if I create two separate billing accounts, both linked to the same payment profile?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing#cluster_management_fee_and_free_tier) says

> The cluster management fee of $0.10 per cluster per hour (charged in 1 second increments) applies to all GKE clusters irrespective of the mode of operation, cluster size or topology.
>
> The GKE free tier provides $74.40 in monthly credits per billing account that are applied to zonal and Autopilot clusters. If you only use a single Zonal or Autopilot cluster, this credit will at least cover the complete cost of that cluster each month. Unused free tier credits are not rolled over, and cannot be applied to any other SKUs (for example, they cannot be applied to compute charges, or the cluster fee for Regional clusters).

On average, I consume $74 a month for a single zonal cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). This amount is just within the limit of the free promotional credits offered per billing account. However, if I were to operate two clusters, I would exceed the promotional credit limit halfway through the month and would start incurring charges for the service.

Would creating two separate billing accounts (**but both linked to the same Google payment profile**), allow each account to take advantage of its own set of promotional credits, effectively doubling the amount of free usage available? Is that actually the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me your issue requires billing specialists for GCP. You may check this link for more details and assistance.[1]

[1[

https://cloud.google.com/support/billing#contact-billing-support